# HDMI audio not working on NVIDIA nForce 780a chipset

Tags: pulseaudio

I am on Ubuntu 13.10 with an AMD Phenom II X4 processor and nForce 780a chipset. I do not have a video card installed. When I use the built in hdmi port, I get good video, but no audio, even after switching the output device. I tried installing the proprietary chipset drivers, switching profile in pulseaudio volume control.

Running `pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo` doesn't do anything either.

this is the output from `aplay -L`:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, AD198x Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

I am at wits end here and feeling rather unimpressed with ALSA and PulseAudio. Is there anything special that needs to be done for my particular chipset?

Using `pavucontrol`: The device under output is "HDMI / DisplayPort" and is "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output" on the configuration tab. It should be working, but it's not.

```
pactl stat
Currently in use: 1 blocks containing 63.9 KiB bytes total.
Allocated during whole lifetime: 131881 blocks containing 230.7 MiB bytes total.
Sample cache size: 0 B
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 28
Server Protocol Version: 28
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 19
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: media
Host Name: PlexBMC-Serve
Server Name: pulseaudio
Server Version: 4.0
Default Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_07.0.hdmi-stereo
Default Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_07.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor
Cookie: 9d20:6867

pactl list sinks
Sink #0
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_07.0.hdmi-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 5
    Mute: no
    Volume: 0: 100% 1: 100%
            0: -0.00 dB 1: -0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_07.0.hdmi-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.id = "HDMI 0"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "3"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xfe020000 irq 20"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:07.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0774"
        device.product.name = "MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "hdmi:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "hdmi-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Nvidia MCP77/78 HDMI"
        alsa.components = "HDA:11d4198b,1043829b,00100400 HDA:10de0002,10de0101,00100000"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority: 5900)
    Active Port: hdmi-output-0
    Formats:
        ac3-iec61937, format.rate = "[ 32000, 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000 ]"
        eac3-iec61937, format.rate = "[ 32000, 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000 ]"
        dts-iec61937, format.rate = "[ 32000, 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000 ]"
        pcm
```

Comment: The device under output is "HDMI / DisplayPort" and is "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output" on the configuration tab. It should be working, but it's not.

Comment: [pactl stat](http://pastebin.com/e1wYXejN) and [pactl list sinks](http://pastebin.com/NZYvwNwG)

Comment: Configuration seems ok, So when you start a player (play any thing), do you see moving bar (of signl) in outputs tab at "HDMI / DisplayPort"? could you join chat room:sneetsher

Comment: Sorry. There is a moving bar of signal. I am in the chatroom, but I don't see you.

Comment: Optical and analog work. Only HDMI is broken.